# ¿Cómo solucionar estos problemas de xampp?

Tags: xampp

Soy nuevo en usar php y me salen estos errores:

> Apache Service detected with wrong path Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   Found Path: "E:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>
> Problem detected!
>   Port 80 in use by ""c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 8268!
>   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
>   MySQL Service detected with wrong path
>   Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
>   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   Found Path: E:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=e:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
>   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
>
> Problem detected!
>   Port 3306 in use by "c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.26\bin\mysqld.exe wampmysqld64"! MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

¿Alguien que fuera tan amable de explicarme por favor?

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y dale formato al error para que sea más entendible... Date una vuelta por [ask] para más información

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Los puertos `80` y `3306` estan siendo ocupados por wamp y mysql. adicional verifica las rutas donde instalaste xampp. Pasate por este enlace [¿Cómo ejecutar xampp y wamp en tu computadora local?](http://www.finalhints.com/how-to-run-xampp-and-wamp-on-your-local-computer/)

Answer (score 0):

Este error lo solucioné eliminando los servicios del mysql y el del Apache2.4 mediante el cmd.

sc delete mysql

sc delete Apache2.4

Después de realizar esto cerré el XAMPP y lo volví a iniciar y listo, funcionó correctamente. Espero les sirva.